# Laravel App HTTP Request to local API on same nginx Docker container

Tags: php, laravel, networking, nginx, docker

docker-compose.yml

```
web:
  build: ./docker-images/nginx
  ports:
    - "8080:80"
  volumes:
    - ./:/var/www/
    - ./docker-conf/vhost.conf:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/vhost.conf
  links:
    - php

php:
  image: nmcteam/php56
  volumes:
    - ./docker-conf/php-fpm.conf:/etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf
    - ./:/var/www
```

nginx vhost.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    server_name myapi.dev;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /var/www/myapi/public;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    server_name mywebapp.dev;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /var/www/mywebapp/public;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

windows hosts file

```
192.168.99.2        mywebapp.dev
192.168.99.2        myapi.dev
```

docker vm ip

```
$ docker-machine ip default
192.168.99.2
```

Okay, so you've seen the above chunks of code and configurations...

I tried to do a GET request using Guzzle from within mywebapp to the location `myapi.dev/resource?apikey=myapikey`. I have tried with `google.com` so I know it works, I just don't think I know how things should be requested locally.

Some of the other domains I have tried to no avail:

```
127.0.0.1/resource?...
192.168.99.2/resource?...
0.0.0.0/resource?...
172.17.0.2/resource?...
```

I know the code works because I've done so with xampp and it worked but not the above docker configuration.

Answer (score 1):

If I am right in understanding what you've written, you have added the myapi.dev to the windows host file but not the docker vm?  If your website is running in the docker VM you will need to add the code there otherwise it will not resolve the custom DNS that you have used (and I'm assuming that you don't actually have that domain for global DNS purposes).

Because your nginx configuration uses specific names, you can not use the local IP addresses since they will not be resolved to those nginx server entries.  You'll end up getting a default nginx server if one is defined.

Comment: so do I edit the `default` machine's host file or the container's? I'm confused by how docker's network is set up. Anyway, I'll give it a go and update the resolution (tick and acceptance and whatnot) if I got it to work. Thanks for the answer!